# Search column for value x and copy userform data to applicable row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have got the below code I assigned k as the textbox value to check that it is working properly (seems it is) but it still refuses to search column A and simply executes the Else argument.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim FoundCell As Range
Set FoundCell = Sheets("WATCH LOG").Range("A:A").Find(What:=WN.Value)
    k = FoundCell.Value

If k = WN.Value Then
        j = FoundCell.Row
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 6).Value = Me.DMN.Value
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 7).Value = Me.DWN.Value
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 8).Value = Me.DOE.Value
End If
    Else
    MsgBox "WATCH NOT FOUND"

End Sub
```

*Added note due to comment:*

`WN`, `DMN`, `DWN` and `DOE` are userform text fields.

Comment: Your posted code is broken. Please correct that. I guess the issue is with the find method. As you only specified `What` all other parameters may have values you do not expect. Have a look at [Important_Note_about_Find_Parameters](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/#Important_Note_about_Find_Parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the purpose of your code, you want to find a search string as entered in the 1st textbox `WN` in column A and write the subsequent textbox strings `DMN`, `DWN` and  `DOE` to a given offset within the found row.

Some hints to multiple issues:

- declare all your variables (use `Option Explicit`)
- use fully qualified range references
- referring to worksheets prefer the `Worksheets` collection, as `Sheets` may include shapes as well
- be strict in indenting code to avoid wrong `If` .. `Else` ..`EndIf` constructions as you did (btw this would raise a compile error)
- provide for cases where you don't find your search string e.g. via `If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then`; this allows you to avoid extra checks like `If k = WN.Value Then` because if you found the search item, it is identical

Furthermore I demonstrated a way to write all subsequent textbox values to a given offset of +5 columns right to the found cell in column A via `Array(DMN, DWN, DOE)` by one code line :)

```
Option Explicit                               ' declaration head of code module

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose: find search string of 1st textbox and write subsequent strings to found row
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WATCH LOG")     ' use fully qualified range reference
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Set FoundCell = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=WN, LookAt:=xlWhole,  MatchCase:=False)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then          ' search string found
        FoundCell.Offset(0, 5).Resize(1, 3) = Array(DMN, DWN, DOE)
    Else                                      ' provide for non-results
        MsgBox "WATCH NOT FOUND"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much!! Has worked perfectly and your advice will certainly help in future!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim FoundCell As Range
Set FoundCell = Sheets("WATCH LOG").Range("A:A").Find(What:=WN) 'Take away the .Value within the Find
    k = FoundCell.Value

If k = WN.Value Then
        j = FoundCell.Row
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 6).Value = Me.DMN.Value
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 7).Value = Me.DWN.Value
            Sheets("WATCH LOG").Cells(j, 8).Value = Me.DOE.Value
End If
    Else
    MsgBox "WATCH NOT FOUND"

End Sub
```

Comment: Are some of the variables used in this code instantiated in a separate, parent macro? If so, you may want to check this site out https://www.thesmallman.com/pass-variables-between-macros

Comment: No variable from other macros, The WN, DMN,DWN,DOE are userform text fields